# Typecast to a specific struct type by its string name

Tags: go, struct, type-assertion

I would like to typecast a specific variable to a specific defined struct/interface by using the string name value of the struct/interface.

For example:

```
type Testing interface{}
```

and new variable

```
stringName := "Testing"
newTestingVariable.(stringName)
```

Is this possible by chance? Perhaps using reflection?

Cheers

Comment: Not exactly that but there is a feature request to create new type names using reflect. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16522 . There is also the plugin package. https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible. Go is a statically typed language, which means types of variables and expressions must be known at compile-time.

In a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

> ```
> x.(T)
> ```
>
> [...] If the type assertion holds, the value of the expression is the value stored in `x` and its type is `T`.

So you use type assertion to get (or test for) a value of a type you specify.

When you would do:

```
stringName := "Testing"
newTestingVariable.(stringName)
```

What would be the *type* of the result of the type assertion? You didn't tell. You specified a `string` value containing the type name, but this can only be decided at *runtime*. (Yes, in the above example the compiler could track the value as it is given as a constant value, but in the general case this is not possible at compile time.)

So at compile time the compiler could only use `interface{}` as the type of the result of the type expression, but then what's the point?

If the point would be to dynamically test if `x`'s type is `T` (or that if the interface value `x` implements `T`), you can use reflection for that (package [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)). In this case you would use a `reflect.Type` to specify the type to be tested, instead of a `string` representation of its name.

Comment: Ah okay.. I had my suspensions that would be the case. Thank you for that good explanation.