# How to get access to a custom type in a reflect.Call return?

Tags: go, reflection

I know its not idiomatic to write generic functions in Go, but I want to explore my options before I dive into the `go generate`.

The problem I have is that the `Value.Call()` returns a slice where the element I interested in is a pointer to a custom struct. Seems like I cant find a way to access this.

```golang
returns := listMethod.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(filter)})
fmt.Println(returns)
```

output

```
[<vspk.EnterpriseProfilesList Value> <*bambou.Error Value>]
```

type definition:

```
type EnterpriseProfilesList []*EnterpriseProfile
```

I want to get access to the `vspk.EnterpriseProfilesList`, but I am struggling to make it.

If I try to retrieve the underlying value like this:

```
returns := listMethod.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(filter)})
ret1 := returns[0].Interface()
fmt.Println(ret1)
```

I receive

```
[0xc0000fc7e0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Value.Call()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call) returns a value of type `[]reflect.Value`. What you're interested in is the first value of that slice: `returns[0]`.

This will be of course of type [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value). To extract the value wrapped in it, use [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface).

This will be of type `interface{}`. If you need the concrete type, use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
returns[0].Interface().(spk.EnterpriseProfilesList)
```

For example:

```
if list, ok := returns[0].Interface().(spk.EnterpriseProfilesList); ok {
    // here list is of type spk.EnterpriseProfilesList
} else {
    // it was nil or not of type spk.EnterpriseProfilesList
}
```

Comment: thanks @icza, can I somehow make the type assertion dynamic? i.e. if I only have a string "EnterpriseProfilesList", can I use it in the type assertion statement?

Comment: @RomanDodin No, Go is a statically typed language. See [Typecast to a specific struct type by its string name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014890/typecast-to-a-specific-struct-type-by-its-string-name/47015211#47015211); and [How to create a variable with needed type instead of type assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275975/how-to-create-a-variable-with-needed-type-instead-of-type-assertion/52276079#52276079).